# What ? SDL won't open window?

Tags: macos, sdl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/sdl.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Fen", 640, 480, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    std::cout << SDL_GetError();
    SDL_Delay(3000);
    return 0;
}
```

why I have No window opened ? It is strange....
The build is ok but no window is opened

For info, I am using a Mac

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your window has been created. You can see the cmd application icon in OS X dock.

The real problem you can't get a positive feedback is that this window is empty and displays nothing. The following codes will fill it white.

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Fen", 640, 480, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

auto screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );

//Fill the surface white
SDL_FillRect( screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF ) );

//Update the surface
SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );

SDL_Delay(3000);

//Destroy window
SDL_DestroyWindow( window );

//Quit SDL subsystems
SDL_Quit();
```